# Condition so that an integer $x$ is $x \neq pa + qb$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Suppose that I want to form an integer $x$ so that $x \neq pa + qb$ where $a$ and $b$ are fixed integers(that is, these integers are set from the start) and $p,q$ are free integers. All numbers are nonzero.

What is the condition of $x$ given $a,b$ to satisfy the aforementioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Bézout's Identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezoutsIdentity.html), we can always find $p,q$ such that $$(a,b)=p\cdot a+q\cdot b$$

So, we can always find $p,q$ such that $$x=p\cdot a+q\cdot b\iff (a,b)\mid x$$

Hence, if $ (a,b)\not\mid x$ we won't find $p,q$ in integers such  that $x=p\cdot a+q\cdot b$